# Android support library 23.2.0 error in setting style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library

I'm using all the latest tools and gradle versions for Materializing my app.
Previously, everything working fine but now the button style colored is causing error in versions lower than Lollipop.

The parent theme i'm using-

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

and Defined colors in theme-

> "colorPrimary", "colorPrimaryDark", "colorAccent", "colorButtonNormal", colorControlNormal", "colorControlActivated", "colorControlHighlight"

here is the Button view--

```
line:114 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/act_first_lock_btn_next"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/next" />
```

here is the crash in kitkat 4.4.4-

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #114: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
```

if i remove the style ***style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"***, error is gone but no colors on button.

The last thing i changed before the error occurred was updated to support lib version 23.2.0.

**--UPDATE--**

It is definitely a bug in support lib 23.2.0.
Reported bug here-
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201937

Chris Banes (google dev) has merged the issue to-

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817

Comment: what is Gradle version ?

Comment: have you made changes in gradle ?

Comment: none but in app's build.gradle to support "app:srcCompat" thing.

Comment: I have same issue. Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored style is broken on pre-lollipop and lead to crash

Comment: @deviant thanks for verifying.. i request you to follow the link to bug report i updated in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on other machine and its a bug in support library version 23.2.0

So I've reported it on 
[AOSP issue tracker here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201937).

If you are having same issue...do star the issue on above link.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Here comes the support library version 23.2.1...
works like a charm!!

**UPDATE**
Here comes the Support lib 23.3.0...
and the charm goes away...
complete story [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484748/appcompat-23-3-support-vectors-no-longer-work/36484749).

I guess support library needs to be well tested before final release..

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `style="..."` to `android:theme="..."`