# AppCompat 23.3 Support Vectors no longer work?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I was using the support vector drawables added in [Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) along with AppCompat. I was using vector drawables both with `app:srcCompat` and inside a `StateListDrawable` so I could use them with `android:drawableLeft` for my TextView.

Since upgrading to the 23.3.0 version of AppCompat, only the vectors in `app:srcCompat` are working. Whenever I reference it the other way I get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package.name/.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Button
 ...
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Button
 ...
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #14: invalid drawable tag vector
  at android.graphics.d
```

What changed that now causes my support vector drawables to fail in some cases?

Comment: finally I don't get it. if I wanna use vector just remove vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true and using app:srcCompat or ordinari android:src ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37864531/3870932

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Update:** They enable it again in Support Library 23:

> For AppCompat users, we’ve added an opt-in API to re-enable support Vector Drawables from resources (the behavior found in 23.2) via AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); - keep in mind that this still can cause issues with memory usage and problems updating Configuration instances, hence why it is disabled by default.

Check [this link: 23.4.0 available now](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/B7QhFkWZ6YX)

-----------------------------------------------------------

As per the [release announcement for Android Support Library 23.3](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne):

> For AppCompat users, we’ve decided to remove the functionality which let you use vector drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices due to issues found in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1 [ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205236, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204708 ]. Using `app:srcCompat` and `setImageResource()` continues to work.

So this is an expected behavior change. You'll have to use non-vector graphics for any case not handled by `srcCompat`.

If you'd like to continue to use vectors prior to API 21, **you can remove the line**

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

(or the equivalent if you using the 1.5 Gradle plugin as shown in the [23.2 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)).

This will cause Android Studio to generate PNGs at compile time for apps with a minSdkVersion less than API 21 while using your vectors on API 21+ devices, allowing you to keep the same code as with `23.2.1` at the cost of additional APK size.

Comment: can i use it with android gradle plugin 2.0.0?

Comment: @ArnavM. the version of Gradle Plugin does not change anything (only how you enable support vector drawables)

Comment: @IanLake the InstantRun feature requires gradle 2.1.0-alpha5 .. can't use generatedDencities with that?

Comment: So basically app:srcCompat is useless now, since if we disable the vector drawables support library we end up with all the vectors in PNG anyway. What about all the "drawableStart/drawableEnd/etc" benefits, they are now gone, and it looks impossible to mix vector and non-vector assets in XML layouts due to this regression which crashes the app if a drawable has a vector.

Comment: @AdrianCrețu - well, if all you are using support vectors for is through srcCompat or at runtime with `VectorDrawableCompat.create()`, then you can continue to use support vectors prior to Lollipop. There's a [data binding technique](https://plus.google.com/+LisaWrayZeitouni/posts/MxJ2PVpBMbf) that seeks to restore this functionality by using `VectorDrawableCompat.create()` under the covers.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - this implies that the developer should use srcCompat and have vector drawables only for these cases, while attributes like drawableLeft (or even src with a StateList) NEED to only use PNG drawables. Because PNGs are usually generated from vectors, we therefore need to disable the vector support lib, so in turn srcCompat is no longer useful, since we'll have PNGs for all drawables anyway. How is this useful then? I'm asking for the pre-Lollipop use-case, ofcourse.

Comment: @AdrianCrețu - Yep, the tooling unfortunately is an all or nothing thing when it comes to generating PNGs from vectors as part of your build. Of course, you could use vectors for only the srcCompat cases and manually generated PNGs for non-srcCompat cases and skip the Android Studio generation of PNGs entirely, allowing you to keep `useSupportLibrary = true` and only use vectors where possible.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I removed vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true but app crash when using srcCompat for vector graphics, but works with ordinary android:drawable ! why this happens?

Comment: @Kenji: if you've removed useSupportLibrary, then you don't need srcCompat either. Just use src

Comment: Should it work with keyboard icons (android:keyIcon)?

Comment: Simply use `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`. Problem solved. No need to keep pngs for lower versions. Even `srcCompat` is not needed.

Comment: @HarishGyanani - if you are using AppCompat, any `ImageView` in your layouts will automatically be replaced with `AppCompatImageView`. That is precisely why `app:srcCompat` and `setImageResource()` work.

Comment: I can show you so many cases where images are not shown even if `srcCompat` is used and other things have been done. (like vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true and  AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); ). `AppCompatImageView` always work.

Comment: @HarishGyanani - then you are using the wrong layout inflater. Always use `LayoutInflater.from(activityContext)` or `activity.getLayoutInflater()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I got your point and found out my problem. thanks

Answer (score 18):

VectorDrawable support for pre-Lollipop was added in Support Library 23.2.0, then partially removed in 23.3.0. In 23.4.0 and above (at least 25.1.0), that removed part is back but behind an optional flag (because it comes with a price).

To sum up: **in Support Library 23.4.0 to at least 25.1.0, you can get VectorDrawable to work *in some cases***.

I have made [this diagram](https://medium.com/@ferrand.d/can-you-and-should-you-use-vector-drawables-a-cheatsheet-32a2e1cc2ecf) to help.

[image: VectorDrawable cheatsheet]

Comment: That is a sweet diagram :)

Answer (score 5):

To use vectors as compoundDrawables ( ex. for textview ) without using

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

which leads to documented high memory usage, just inflate the vector using

```
Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable( getContext(), R.drawable.vector_resID );
if( drawable != null ) drawable.setBounds( 0, 0, iconSize, iconSize );
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative( textView, null, null, drawable, null);
```

This is the way the navDrawer works

Comment: You can also use `TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()`, then you don't need to set the bounds yourself.