# Programmatically tint a Support Vector

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

Android Studio  version 2.1, gradle version 2.1.0, please correct me if you spot any misinterpretations :)

I am confused about support vectors in the support library 23.3.0. Specifically what I would like to do is tint an image button programmatically, whose src is defined is a vector drawable. From what I can tell this is not possible on pre-lollipop now.

I have read several related posts about the changes:
[23.2.0 announcement and changes](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html):

> As of Android Support Library 23.3.0, support vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource().

Does the above mean that vector xmls can only be used pre-Lollipop via srcCompat or setImageResource(), and therefore **cannot be dynamically tinted**?

Here is my basic image button:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_exit_community_button"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

*Works on Lollipop and above only:*

```
    Drawable bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(bg, headerTitleColor);
    exitButton.setImageDrawable(bg);
```

Attempting this pre-lollipop throws:
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_exit_to_app_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200bf`

*Also works on Lollipop and above only*

```
    Drawable bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(bg, headerTitleColor);
    exitButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp);
```

This throws the same error on pre-Lollipop.

However if I remove `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` as pointed out [by Ian Lake here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484749/1866373), with the intent of having the build tools auto-generate pngs for pre-Lollipop devices, **the pngs do not tint on pre-lollipop**, so I'm back to square one.

I have also tried specifying the vector via `srcCompat` and retrieving it programmatically but I don't think I've been able to achieve that, even though it works on post-Lollipop if the vector is specified using `src` instead.

So the situation for 23.3.0 seems to be:

- Post-Lollipop: `src` and `srcCompat` accept vectors, only `src` can be
  retrieved from the view as a drawable for tinting programmatically.
  Referencing vectors in code is possible using getDrawable, and they
  can be tinted.
- Pre-Lollipop: srcCompat only can accept vectors, cannot be retrieved
  programmatically from the view for tinting.  `setImageResource` can
  accept vectors, but only if `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = false`, and tinting does not work. Similarly referencing vectors in code is not
  possible unless `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = false` and tinting
  does not work.

*Working on all versions using pngs:*

```
   Drawable bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.ic_nav_exit_community);
   DrawableCompat.setTint(bg, headerTitleColor);
   exitButton.setImageDrawable(bg);
```

*Addendum:*

This technique also works on post-Lollipop, but like the others on pre-Lollipop I get the drawable, but no tinting:

```
    Drawable bg = VectorDrawableCompat.create(a.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp, null);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(bg, headerTitleColor);
    exitButton.setImageDrawable(bg);
```

**KIND OF SOLUTION:**

Thanks to [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898394/1866373) answer so far the only fool-proof way I can come up with to tint a support vector is to set a color filter on it - this means the `DrawableCompat.setTint()` function is seemingly not functional for me if the drawable in question is a support vector. I'm not sure if this is a legit bug, expected behavior or if I'm just doing something wrong!

Here is the solution I'm going with for the moment:

```
    Drawable bg;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        bg = VectorDrawableCompat.create(a.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp, null);
        exitButton.setColorFilter(headerTitleColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
    else {
        bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(bg, headerTitleColor);
    }
    exitButton.setImageDrawable(bg);
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the Vector Compat library to create your drawble?  i.e         VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_action_add,null)

Comment: I've updated my answer, looks like that 's yet another technique (!) to do the same kind of thing but tinting it doesn't work on pre-L

Comment: it is not another techique, this is how `VectorDrawableCompat` should be created and if you read `DrawableCompat` docs you would see that [this](http://pastebin.com/CzEbnP9k) just works

Comment: Okay thank you! I would like to do more testing but it looks like the crucial missing component for me was the call to `wrap()` the drawable. This seems to be required for pre-L, along with the call to `create` rather than just loading the drawable or referencing it by it's view. I had actually tried those two ways with a wrap call, but not the `create`! If you want to post an answer telling me to wrap it I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

first of all you should use `VectorDrawableCompat#create`, once you have your `Drawable` you have to call `DrawableCompat#wrap`:

> Potentially wrap drawable so that it may be used for tinting across
>   the different API levels, via the tinting methods in this class.

so your code would look like this:

```
ImageView iv = ....
Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp, null);
d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
DrawableCompat.setTint(d, headerTitleColor);
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: i have use this same on another place it was working fine but this time its not working i don't why

Comment: ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
        new ContextThemeWrapper(parent.getContext(), R.style.CalendarCell_CalendarDate));
    imageView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);

    parent.addView(imageView,
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50, CENTER_VERTICAL));
    parent.setDayOfMonthTextView(imageView);

Comment: Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_circle, null);
                    d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(d, dailyLim.intValue());
                    cellView.getDayOfMonthImageView().setImageDrawable(d);

Comment: what is `dailyLim.intValue()`? for testing replace it with `Color.RED`

Comment: let me try this

Comment: working with Color.Red my dailyLim.intValue() is also working with setBackgroundColor but not with setTint.

Comment: yes worked but please guide me why it's not working with my dailyLim.intValue because this dailyLim.intValue is working in setBackgroundColor

Comment: i have no idea what do you have in it, tried to `Log.d` its value with `Integer.toHexString()`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(int%2C%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) method of ImageView:

`imageView.setColorFilter(headerTitleColor, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);`

Comment: For the moment this seems to be the best solution, although I'm not happy about it!

Answer (score 2):

Another handy solution with Kotlin:

```
fun Context.drawableWithColor(@DrawableRes drawableRes: Int, @ColorInt color: Int): Drawable? {
    val pic = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableRes)
    pic?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    return pic
}
```

Use is as simple as:

```
val drawable = context.drawableWithColor(R.drawable.your_awesome_drawable, Color.BLUE)
```