# Set vector drawable programmatically pre Lollipop

Tags: android, vector, drawable, android-resources

Very common problem with a twist to which I couldn't find a solution for.
I am setting my vector programmatically. I want to be able to change the tint color programmatically too.
Found some solutions such as
[Programmatically tint a Support Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897687/programmatically-tint-a-support-vector/36907312#36907312)

```
ImageView iv = ....
Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_exit_to_app_24dp, null);
d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
DrawableCompat.setTint(d, headerTitleColor);
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The main problem comes with

```
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I found that prelolipop only accepts setting view's drawable with

```
iv.setImageResource(int resource)
```

I couldn't find any solutions for setting it with a drawable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AppCompatImageView which has [setImageDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method.

Comment: Actually problem was in setting up drawable properly. If using
Drawable vectorIcon = VectorDrawableCompat.create(view.getResources(), vectorDrawableSource, themeSource);

It works just fine! 
Thank you!