# Vector Drawable with Gradient fill color not supporting below API 24

Tags: android, kotlin, vector, gradient, drawable

Vector drawable of image contains Gradient colors, which are not showing in imageview for below API version of 24, i am using Android-Studio 3.1

***color.xml:***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:centerX="143.856"
android:centerY="64.935"
android:gradientRadius="220.29005"
android:type="radial">
<item
    android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:offset="0" />
<item
    android:color="#FFEFEFEF"
    android:offset="0.412" />
<item
    android:color="#FFC7C9CA"
    android:offset="0.813" />
<item
    android:color="#FFBDBFC1"
    android:offset="1" />
</gradient>
```

***ic_card.xml***

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="288dp"
android:height="130dp"
android:autoMirrored="true"
android:viewportWidth="288"
android:viewportHeight="130">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/tohumkart1"
    android:pathData="M0,0H288V130H0Z"></path>
<path
</vector>
```

***build.gradle:***

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

***Application.java :***

```
   static
{
   AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

***implementaion:***

```
 val cardImage = creditCardModel?.let { cardHelper.getCardImage(it) }
                 cardImage?.let { brCardImage.setImageResource(it) }
```

***tried:***

```
cardHelper.getDrawable(ApplicationContext.getInstance().activityContext,cardImage!!)
```

Is there any way to reflect gradient colors in imageview under API 23 with Android Studio 3.0.?

Comment: \\ i tried on API 21 and it's working !

Answer (score -1):

i tried on API 21 and it's working !

am working in java not kotlin ,, and i used the drawable resource in xml not in code

and i didn't use this part

> AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()

and as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167117/) you have to use **setImageDrawable** not **setImageResource**

[image]

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_saleplusgoldkart.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02024e. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() for more info.
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)

Comment: What is your grade version? My grade version is 2.3.3

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip