# Android vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true is stopping app

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

If I use **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** in gradle then run the app it stopped unfortunately. If I remove **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** the app works.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.helikanon.firstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

The errors :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.helikanon.firstapp/com.helikanon.firstapp.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class Button
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
.
.
.
```

The app is crashing when I use Api 16 and Api 19 but When I use Api 23 it works.

Comment: Take a look at this article - http://chris.banes.me/2016/02/25/appcompat-vector/. I had this problem too.

Comment: I did exactly in this article but still I'm getting error

Comment: I thought you wanted to know the reason for the crash. Anyways, what is the gradle version you're using?

Comment: Gradle version is 2.2.3

Comment: I need to add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true because of I use vector icons and the app must works well(for example drawable tint) for vector icons under API 21

Comment: You can still use vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true, just use ImageButton stead of Button.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You cannot use **Vector Drawables** in any other views except `ImageView` in pre-lollipop.

Please see this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484749/3140227) by google developer advocate.

> For AppCompat users, we’ve decided to remove the functionality which let you use vector drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices due to issues found in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1 [ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205236, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204708 ]. Using `app:srcCompat` and `setImageResource()` continues to work.

If you want to use the **Vector Drawables** pre-lollipop, use can set it programatically by converting it into a drawable.

```
Drawable drawable;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableResId, context.getTheme());
} else {
     drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), drawableResId, context.getTheme());
}

button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Comment: `ContextCompat.getDrawable()` doesn't support vector drawables, using AndroidX provided method does: `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.image)`

Answer (score 23):

I was on one of practice projects trying to learn background tasks and services in Android. When I pulled their sample code then initially it wasn't compiling due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46978566/465053) error. So I added below tag in app's build.gradle file to get rid of compilation issue:

```
android {
    defaultConfig{
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Now, the moment I added this configuration then my app also started to crash in Microsoft Android Simulator exactly the way OP has described.

Since my current focus was to learn about background tasks so I wanted to get started with debugging my app. So, I removed above configuration setting again. In addition to that I also removed an attribute named `android:fillColor` in `path` tag of one of my drawable resources (or you can also replace the value `@color/colorAccent` with a hexadecimal code such as `#FF000000`). After removing(or changing with hexadecimal code) it, my initial compilation error didn't come:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="80dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:pathData="M16.01 7L16 3h-2v4h-4V3H8v4h-0.01C7 6.99 6 7.99 6 8.99v5.49L9.5
18v3h5v-3l3.5-3.51v-5.5c0-1-1-2-1.99-1.99z" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
</vector>
```

After removal it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="80dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:pathData="M16.01 7L16 3h-2v4h-4V3H8v4h-0.01C7 6.99 6 7.99 6 8.99v5.49L9.5
18v3h5v-3l3.5-3.51v-5.5c0-1-1-2-1.99-1.99z" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
</vector>
```

My MS Android emulator had Kitkat(4.4). My code was crashing as my app was trying to use vector drawables on a pre-lollipop version of Android as mentioned in Vipul's accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set:

```
android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to make two modifications to your project. First, set android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in your build.gradle file, and second, use app:srcCompat instead of android:src to refer to vector drawables.

1. Go to your `build.gradle`(Module: app) and add following line to android block. It should look like that.

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "..."
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 27
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // <------
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Refer to the source as *srcCompat* to allow your application to use vector graphics.

   app:srcCompat="@drawable/plane"

Comment: You don't need to specify `android.defaultConfig.` part again if it is nested in `android { defaultConfig { } }` blocks.

Answer (score 6):

If your minSdkVersion 21 or higher you don't need this.

Android 5.0 officially support vector drawables.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

update: As of StuStirling mentioned, below API24 (Android 7.0) you need this if you reference other resources within your vector file.

**Update:**

If your removed the `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` analyze the APK for generated pngs from the vectors. If you find ex: `xxxhdpi-v4` in the drawables put back the useSupportLibrary line.
(I don't reference other drawables from the vectors)

Comment: Not strictly true. To reference other resources from within your vector file on < 24, you need to add `useSupportLibrary = true`

Answer (score 3):

In your case the problem is that **Button** isn't subclass of **ImageView**.

**ImageView** or it's subclasses such as **ImageButton** and **FloatingActionButton** can use the new `app:srcCompat` attribute to reference vector drawables.

To support vector drawable and animated vector drawable you need to add:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

And use `app:srcCompat`

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

You can still use your Vector Drawable by programatically converting it into a drawable using this method provided by AndroidX:

```
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.loading_indeterminate)
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9