# I try to add firebaseUI but show error Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable

Tags: android, firebase

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth
You are using ui-auth need some extra configuration check UI-Auth doc.

Comment: i tryed it but not working else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407811/android-vectordrawables-usesupportlibrary-true-is-stopping-app
Try this.

Comment: Update your version to latest and remove this //noinspection GradleCompatible

Comment: i updated version and delete //noinspection GradleCompatible , didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5' //There is not 16.0.5 version yet
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

And also make sure to have in your top level buil.gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```