# Can't use vector drawables as app icon and imageView source both

Tags: android, vector, android-appcompat

The problem is that if I use a vector image for ImageView, I'll get a warning saying `To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set 'android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`.

However, if I set it to `true`, my other vector drawable for the app's icon will not show, and instead of this, I'll have a default "green robot" icon. I am using API v15 and more, and I know that the vector drawables is included in the appCompat library, but I can't use it for the app's icon and view the source at the same time.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407811/android-vectordrawables-usesupportlibrary-true-is-stopping-app

Comment: @forpas it didn't help because i use ImageView,not different view.
All is ok ImageView, its work in any case - with or without "vector = true" line in gradle file. Warning says add that line - i do, - and icon is not showing. And i can't wrap the icon vector drawable