# InflateException: Error inflating class Button - Crash through play store

Tags: java, android

I have spent a long time looking for an answer to this issue and seem unable to figure it out.

An app I created through "Android Studio" has been working perfectly fine when I create an APK in debug mode, however if I create a bundle and upload it to play store then it crashes on 5 out of 11 devices (including my own) due to the exact same error:

> Issue: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{maxmansung.finaljudgement/maxmansung.finaljudgement.MainScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class Button

What appears to be happening is that the app is unable to open any Buttons at all for some reason. I have tried deleting the button at the point of error but it simply changes to crashing on another button instead.

---

**Error Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: maxmansung.finaljudgement, PID: 20309
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{maxmansung.finaljudgement/maxmansung.finaljudgement.MainScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=58; index=309
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledStringForCookie(AssetManager.java:642)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1279)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:219)
    at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1157)
    at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:109)
    at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:105)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at maxmansung.finaljudgement.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

---

**Game Code**

If I keep the `OnClickListener` parts then the crash continues

```
package maxmansung.finaljudgement;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

import maxmansung.finaljudgement.savedVariables.saveSettings;

public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    saveSettings settings = new saveSettings(this);
    settings.updateFromSave(this);
    Boolean currentTrue = settings.getCurrentTrue();

    Button mainScreenNew = findViewById(R.id.mainScreenNew);
    Button mainScreenCont = findViewById(R.id.mainScreenCont);
    Button mainScreenAchievements = findViewById(R.id.mainScreenAchieve);

    if (currentTrue){
        mainScreenCont.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mainScreenCont.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (settings.achievementsGained()){
        mainScreenAchievements.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mainScreenAchievements.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    final Animation clickAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_click);

    mainScreenNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Intent gamePage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GamePage.class);
                    gamePage.putExtra("continue", false);
                    startActivity(gamePage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            };
            clickAnimation.setAnimationListener(listener);
            view.startAnimation(clickAnimation);
        }
    });
```

---

**XML Page**

If I remove the `drawableLeft` and `drawableStart` parts then the crash changes to what appears to be an identical crash but further back in the XML code

*I have removed the previous code as it does not impact the crash*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="maxmansung.finaljudgement.MainScreen">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenAchieve"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/achievement_icon"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/achievement_icon"
    android:text="@string/mainScreenAchievements"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainScreenCont" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error sometimes happens because there is a drawable involved.  
I see in your xml this `@drawable/achievement_icon` is used for the `Button` with id `mainScreenAchieve`.  
Is there a case that you have stored this drawable in a folder like `drawable-v24` only and not in the main `drawable` folder?  
If this is the case then copy and paste it in the main `drawable` folder too.  
Otherwise in the devices with lower version this drawable is unavailable and this leads to an app crash.

Comment: I've tried removing the drawable icon (and the entire button) but the crash continues, it appears to be specific to the act of inflating an button

Comment: Yes, hence why I tested out removing the button with the drawable, however that resulted in this error:
"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class Button"

Comment: Yes, the crash continues without the style and the error remains the same

Comment: Then remove the attributes one by one and test. I would start by leaving only 1 Button and removing 1st its text and go on like this with the other attributes.

Comment: Ok, I will work my way through that. You think it must be specific to a single aspect of the buttons rather than a top level issue regarding the use of buttons in the app overal?

Comment: Since you don't use any 3d party library or widget and this is the common Button I can't see why this would cause a problem but try it. Remove all the buttons and see what happens.

Comment: So it seems that after a **lot** of experiementing there are 2 things causing the crash

1. The use of `onClickListener` in the main code
2. The use of `drawableStart` and `drawableLeft` in the XML

By removing both of these I can stop the crash

Comment: *The use of drawableStart and drawableLeft* means problem with the drawable and *The use of onClickListener* means problem with the animation.

Comment: It would seem so, unfortunatly I don't have enough experience to be able to PM you so I'll just keep commenting. Is there any advice as to what could be causing both of these things or any details I could show that might help make it clearer?

I've built the game so that its compatable with v16 and up, do I need seperate folders for images and animations for v21?

Comment: Keep all the drawables and animations inside their main folders `drawable` and `anim`. Create other folders like `drawable-v21` and paste the drawbles there too and experiment. But deal with 1 problem at a time. First remove the animations and check the problem with the drawables.

Comment: Ok, so it appears there are 1 or 2 gradle errors due to an update of the android studio software twice during the development. This removed of one issue so it now works on 8 of 11 devices

I believe the issue with the image in the button may be due to using a vector image (xml file) on the button. Is this a known issue?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407811/android-vectordrawables-usesupportlibrary-true-is-stopping-app

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to the `text` setting. Is your `strings.xml` malformed? Or is it missing from certain build types?

Also - Having a `+` in this line: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainScreenCont"` can cause problems. It doesn't need the `+`.

Comment: I can remove the "+" but it doesn't make a difference to the crashes. I have also Isolated the crash down to 2 influences:
1. The images in 3rd button
2. The use of onClickListeners

Both of these cause the crash and removing only one of them causes it to continue

Comment: So, if you remove the `drawable` references from your snippet above, it works? If so, have you tried setting it programmatically, instead, to see if that still crashes?

Comment: It seems that after a lot of work I have discovered it is due to using a vector image within a button which doesn't work for pre v24 OS.

I am also having a problem with the animations, I suspect this is also due to using it on a button

Comment: Ah! Look up `useVectorCompat`. I'm away from my machine, or I would help more specifically with that set up.